# home folder changes when using java classes from matlab

Tags: java, matlab, resources, jar, filepath

I am writing a java application with a matlab ui. For this I use java objects in matlab as explained here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f4873.html

those java classes reference (using a relative path) to resources in some other folder in the parent map. In eclipse or as an executable jar this all works fine.

**The problem is** that when classes are used in matlab the homefolder changes. So instead of looking in JAR/resources or PROJECTMAP/resources it looks for the resources in MATLAB/resources and returns a file not found exception.

**how I currently solved it** is kinda lame:
I simply put a copy of the resource folder in the MATLAB directory which makes the code execute.
Yet this is a poor solution.

**What I would want is**

1: to include the resource folder in the jar (generated in eclipse) an make it possible to use these classes in matlab (in short: independency current directory)

2: Being able to run the same code from eclipse (to debug/profile...).

3: That the code should execute independantly of the location the jar is in as long as it is added to the matlab classpath. (so the jar does not have to be in a specific folder (eg MATLAB folder))

So I 'simply' need a way to specify the location of the resource folder **in my code** as to achieve 1,2,3 (1,2 most important).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're reading and what you're doing with these resources (so this might not be the correct solution for your case), but you indeed might want to put these on your classpath. If you put them in their own source folder in eclipse you can setup your build to include them in your jar. ([Maven](http://maven.apache.org) by convention has a /src/main/resources directory that is for sticking arbitrary files into a the compiled jar).

With these resources on the classpath... You can then use the classloader to load files through getClass().[getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) or getResource() and run with it.

Comment: Note that if you want to be able to access resources in jars from Matlab, you need those jars on your static classpath.  Having them on the dynamic classpath doesn't work.